# Pasando de tipo objeto a string en php

Tags: php, test

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para automatizar tests con codeception usando robo, para hacerlos de forma paralela.
Los test los llamo desde "RoboFile", con esta función;

```
public function parallelRun()
    {

    $url = 'D:/Programas/xampp/htdocs/robo2/tests/jesusApp.json'; // path to JSON file
    $data = file_get_contents($url); // put contents of the file into a variable
    $jesusApp = json_decode($data,true); // decode the JSON 

    $numberOfTrainees = $jesusApp["numberOfTrainees"];

        $parallel = $this->taskParallelExec();

            for ($i=1;$i<=$numberOfTrainees;$i++) {

                string $args= "ola";
                $parallel->process(
                $this->taskCodecept() // use built-in Codecept task
                    ->suite('acceptance') // run acceptance tests
                    ->group("paracept_$i") // for all paracept_* groups
                    ->arg(string $args)
                    ->xml("tests/_log/result_$i.xml") // save XML results
                );
            }

    return $parallel->run();
    }
```

Como veis, con la línea `->arg(string $args)` lo que estoy intentando es pasar una variable a cada test.
Lo recibo en el test de esta forma:
`public function loginSuccessfully(AcceptanceTester $I,$args)`
Pero cuando lo intento utilizar, me dice que no puede convertir del tipo Codeception\Scenario como un string.
Como puedo convertirlo a string o, conseguir mi propósito de otra forma?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta usar la función `json_encode()` para transformarlo en string y `json_decode()` para devolverlo a objeto.